# Count Unique Value Inside Nested Json

Tags: javascript, json, counting

```
{
    "response_code": "100",
    "total_orders": "302",
    "order_ids": "930777,930783,930788,930791,930793",
    "data": {
        "930777": {
            "response_code": "100",
            "acquisition_date": "2017-04-07 00:06:29",
            "ancestor_id": "930777",
            "affiliate": "1038"
        },
        "930783": {
            "response_code": "100",
            "acquisition_date": "2017-04-07 00:07:59",
            "ancestor_id": "930783",
            "affiliate": "1040"
        },
        "930788": {
            "response_code": "100",
            "acquisition_date": "2017-04-07 00:17:04",
            "ancestor_id": "930788",
            "affiliate": "1038"
        },
        "930791": {
            "response_code": "100",
            "acquisition_date": "2017-04-07 00:20:31",
            "ancestor_id": "930791",
            "affiliate": "1030"
        },
        "930793": {
            "response_code": "100",
            "acquisition_date": "2017-04-07 00:24:34",
            "ancestor_id": "930793",
            "affiliate": "1038"
        }
    }
}
```

Hi I have a returned JSON above from API called. I wonder what is the best method to count the affiliate. I would like to have the result such as

```
Affiliate | Number
1038      | 3
1040      | 1
1030      | 1
```

Some time the return API might have up to 4000 records. I Think there has to be a library that can do the job in short time

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the object using `reduce` on `Object.keys` and accumulate the results like this:

```js
var obj = {"response_code":"100","total_orders":"302","order_ids":"930777,930783,930788,930791,930793","data":{"930777":{"response_code":"100","acquisition_date":"2017-04-07 00:06:29","ancestor_id":"930777","affiliate":"1038"},"930783":{"response_code":"100","acquisition_date":"2017-04-07 00:07:59","ancestor_id":"930783","affiliate":"1040"},"930788":{"response_code":"100","acquisition_date":"2017-04-07 00:17:04","ancestor_id":"930788","affiliate":"1038"},"930791":{"response_code":"100","acquisition_date":"2017-04-07 00:20:31","ancestor_id":"930791","affiliate":"1030"},"930793":{"response_code":"100","acquisition_date":"2017-04-07 00:24:34","ancestor_id":"930793","affiliate":"1038"}}}

var result = Object.keys(obj.data).reduce(function(acc, key) {  // for each key in the data object
  var aff = obj.data[key].affiliate;                            // get the affiliate of the according object
  if(acc[aff]) acc[aff]++;                                      // if we already have have a counter for this affiliate (aff) then increment the value from the accumulator acc
  else         acc[aff] = 1;                                    // otherwise start a counter for this affiliate (initialized with 1)
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all keys and construct object with affiliate number as key and number of occurrences as value.

```js
// jshint esnext: true
const example = {'response_code':'100','total_orders':'302','order_ids':'930777,930783,930788,930791,930793','data':{'930777':{'response_code':'100','acquisition_date':'2017-04-0700:06:29','ancestor_id':'930777','affiliate':'1038'},'930783':{'response_code':'100','acquisition_date':'2017-04-0700:07:59','ancestor_id':'930783','affiliate':'1040'},'930788':{'response_code':'100','acquisition_date':'2017-04-0700:17:04','ancestor_id':'930788','affiliate':'1038'},'930791':{'response_code':'100','acquisition_date':'2017-04-0700:20:31','ancestor_id':'930791','affiliate':'1030'},'930793':{'response_code':'100','acquisition_date':'2017-04-0700:24:34','ancestor_id':'930793','affiliate':'1038'}}};
const results = {};

Object.keys(example.data).forEach(key => {
  const resultsEntry = results[example.data[key].affiliate];
  if (resultsEntry === undefined) {
    results[example.data[key].affiliate] = 1;
  }
  else {
    results[example.data[key].affiliate]++;
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

```css
/* Console output formatting */
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using underscore:

```
var data = // Your json;

var groupedData = _.groupBy(data.data, function(d){return d.affiliate});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afj4dy6v/